# How to center video tag in a div tag?

Tags: css

I cannot seem to position this video tag with the usual "margin: 0px auto 0px auto;"
Help lads! Thanks for looking into this!

```
#wrapper #trailer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    margin-top: 55px;
    width: 987px;
    height: 620px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px solid #009;
}
#wrapper #trailer #close {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 20px;
    right: 231px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#wrapper #trailer video {
        margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px solid #009;
}
```

and html and explaining my scenario as requested :

```
<div id="trailer">
<img id="close" src="images/close.png" alt="close" />
<div id="video">
<video controls  autoplay="autoplay" poster="video/trailer.jpg" width="600"      onclick="if(/Android/.test(navigator.userAgent))this.play();">
<source src="video/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="video/trailer.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="video/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<embed src="video/flashfox.swf" width="600" height="480"  flashVars="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;loop=true&amp;src=trailer.mp4" allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />
</video>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

If you do not know your video's with you can still center it using css transforms:

```
video {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that if you don't know the dimensions of your video beforehand, this is the only solution I found that worked. All other solutions need a fixed sized for the video element.

Comment: This worked well for me and I exhausted all other options. It also works when my video has to be responsive. Thanks!

Comment: This messes with the "three dot menu"

Answer (score 13):

Actually, html5 videos as well as images count as text when it comes to stylesheets.  So, the only changes you would have to make would be in your css code.  Using the `<div id="video>` tag you wrapped the video with, all you would have to add is:

```
#video {
   text-align: center;
   //rest of rules here
}
```

instead of playing with margins all day.

Answer (score 6):

You must set `margin: 0 auto` on the surrounding `<div id="video">`, not the `<video>` tag:

```
#video {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px solid #009;
}
```

instead of

```
#wrapper #trailer video {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px solid #009;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width on the video div in order for `margin: 0 auto`; to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try This
#parant{
 width:100%;
 height:300px;
 text-align:center;
}
#video{
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:auto;
```

}

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.